# ListView objects won't appear on screen until user scrolls down or up

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm creating a page which should read multiple files from the user's device and display the date and name associated with each file.
For each 'entry,' I am creating List Tile which I append to a list of widgets and then display using ListView.
However, the entries only become visible when I scroll up or down on the screen...I've tried using a Column with a SingleChildScrollView or just appending a text widget to the list as a way to debug, but nothing displays...
I learned dart and flutter while building this application so I'm sure a lot of this code is pretty janky, but would appreciate any ideas or tips for this problem!!

**fileToEntry() & entryField() were in their own classes, but I moved them to hopeefully make this a bit more clear!

```
[import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'data_form_page.dart';
import 'file_storage.dart';
import 'file_to_entry.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({
    required this.storage,
  });
  final FileStorage storage;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String form = json.encode({ });

 bool box = false;
  var userList = \[\];
  String curState = '';
  String readFile = '';
  String name = '';
  dynamic attributes = '';
  String date = '';
  String fileContents = '';

  List<String> _fileNames = \[\];

  Future<List<String>> getFiles() async {
    print("in get files");
    List<String> fileNames = \[\];
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = directory.path;
    print(path);
    final dir = Directory(path);
    final List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await dir.list().toList();
    final Iterable<File> files = entities.whereType<File>();
    String strFiles = files.toString().replaceAll('File: ', '');
    strFiles = strFiles.replaceAll("')", '');
    strFiles = strFiles.replaceAll("('", '');
    fileNames = strFiles.split("', '");
    return fileNames;
  }

  fileToEntry(List<String> fileNames) {
    print("in fileToEntry");
    final children = <Widget> \[\];
    for (var count = 0; count < fileNames.length; count++) {
      dynamic fileName = fileNames\[count\].split('/');
      dynamic fullFileName = fileName.last;
      dynamic fileTypeName = fullFileName.split('&');
      dynamic extension = fullFileName.split('.');
      extension = extension\[1\];
      fileTypeName = fileTypeName\[0\].replaceAll("-", " ");
      if(extension == 'json') {
        File(fileNames\[count\]).readAsString().then((String contents) {
          dynamic jsonContents = json.decode(contents);
          for (var count = 0; count < jsonContents\['dataFormsByIds'\].length; count++) {
            if(jsonContents\['dataFormsByIds'\]\[count\]\['name'\] == fileTypeName){
              for(var count2 = 0; count2 < jsonContents\['dataFormsByIds'\]\[count\]\['attributes'\].length; count2++){
                Map item = jsonContents\['dataFormsByIds'\]\[count\]\['attributes'\]\[count2\];
                if (item\['widgetType'\] == 'Date Picker' || item\['widgetType'\] == 'date picker') {
                  date = item\['inputValue'\];
                  children.add(ListTile(
                    title: entryField(fileTypeName, date)));
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
    return ListView(
      children: children,
    );
  }

  entryField(String name, String date){
    print("In entry field");
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>\[
          SizedBox(height: 12),
          Column(
            children: <Widget> \[
              Text(name, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget> \[
                  Container(
                    child: Text(date),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.create_rounded, color: Colors.grey\[800\]),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DataFormPage(storage: FileStorage(),Form: fileContents, typeState: curState,)));
                        //TODO - need to add in opening the file...
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_upload, color: Colors.grey\[800\]),
                      onPressed: () {
                        //TODO - upload logic goes here
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                \],
              ),
            \],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12),
          Container(height: 2, color: Colors.lightGreen\[600\]),
        \],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _setup();
    userList.add(Modal(name: 'Aquatic Insects', isSelected: false));
    userList.add(Modal(name: 'Water Quality', isSelected: false));
    super.initState();
  }

  _setup() async {
    List<String> fileNames = await getFiles();
    print("in _setup");
    print(fileNames);
    setState(() {
      _fileNames = fileNames;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getFiles();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Field Project: " + curState, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey\[800\])),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        actions: <Widget>\[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            width: 60,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Dialog(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                      elevation: 16,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>\[
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 200,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            child: const Text("Select a Field Project Type",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center
                            ),

                          ),
                          ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: userList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index){
                              return Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                height: 50,
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: \[
                                    IconButton(
                                      icon: _iconControl( userList\[index\].isSelected),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          userList.forEach((element) {
                                            element.isSelected = false;
                                          });
                                          userList\[index\].isSelected = true;
                                          curState = userList\[index\].name;
                                          (context as Element).reassemble();
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                        userList\[index\].name
                                    ),
                                  \], //Widget
                                ), //Row
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        \],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ); //Show Dialog
              },
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
              child: Icon(Icons.create_rounded, color: Colors.lightGreen\[600\], size: 30),
            ),
          ),
        \],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>\[
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          ),
          const Text("Saved Observations", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: fileToEntry(_fileNames),
            ),
            // child: FileEntry(
            //   storage: FileStorage(),
            //   fileNames: _fileNames,
            //   typeState: curState,
            // ),
          ),
        \],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if(curState == ''){
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                  elevation: 16,
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>\[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: const Text("Please select an field project type",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center
                        ),
                      ),
                    \],
                  ),
                ); //Return Dialog
              },
            );
          }
          else{
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DataFormPage(storage: FileStorage(), Form: form, typeState: curState,)));
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen\[600\],
      ),
    );
  }

  _iconControl(bool box) {
    if (box == false) {
      return Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank_rounded);
    } else {
      return Icon(
        Icons.check_box_rounded,
        color: Colors.lightGreen\[600\],
      );
    }
  }
}

class Modal {
  String name;
  bool isSelected;
  Modal({required this.name, this.isSelected = false});
}]
```

Comment: You may be able to fix this by simply moving `super.initState()` to be called first. However, a better approach would be to use FutureBuilder: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).